# uitableview have a checkmark on edit mode when selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

when I use edit mode in my tableView,I found there is a **round check mark** on the left.but i don't want it.**how can i delete it**?

My `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` is `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone`

```
self.tableView.editing = YES;
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

i already uncheck the "**Show Selection on Touch**" in xib.
and i check the "**Multiple Selection During Editing**"

Answer (score 0):

It's a result of having `tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true`, which has to be `false` (or uncheck *multiple selection during editing*). If you do want to have multiple-row selection enabled without the checkmark, you may have to set `cell.accessoryView` to something like an empty image. To change the color of the checkmark, you set the cell's tintColor.

Answer (score 0):

set`tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = NO`

Answer (score -1):

If you dont want that round shape checkmark you can do programatically by selecting multiple rows in tableview. Simply follow below codes :

[image]

**Result :**

[image]

I hope you got output as you want. if you still facing any problem let me know.